# Creating a sequence of elements using Xpath 2.0 (as opposed to using XSLT)

Tags: xpath-2.0, xpath-3.0

I'd like to create a sequence of elements in xpath 2.0

You can do something like:

```
('a','b','c')
```

to create a sequence of strings.

I want to do something like:

```
(&lt;a&gt;1&lt;/a&gt;,&lt;a&gt;2&lt;/a&gt;,&lt;a&gt;3&lt;/a&gt;)
```

to create a sequence of elements.

Is this possible? Yes, I know how to do it using XSLT.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In xpath 3.0 you can use `xml-parse()` function as in:

```
parse-xml("&amp;lt;a&amp;gt;1&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;,&amp;lt;a&amp;gt;2&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;,&amp;lt;a&amp;gt;3&amp;lt;/a&amp;gt;")
```

Comment: Saxon 9.3PE and EE support xpath 3.0

Comment: So, the answer (and it is quite obvious) is that this isn't possible using XPath 2.0.